# Why doesn't the ttf fonts work with Vue CLI?

Tags: webpack, fonts, vue-cli

I am working with Vue CLI, and I want to use a font downloaded from the Internet. I think I have configured everything but it just doesn't work.

The structure of the project is like this:

```
+--node_modules
+--public
|  +--index.html
+--src
|  +--assets
|  |  +--css
|  |  +--font
|  |  |  +--font.css
|  |  |  +--FZYXJW.ttf
|  +--components
|  +--App.vue
|  +--main.js
+--babel.config.js
+--vue.config.js
+--package.json
```

Here are the relative codes:

```
// font.css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Youxian';
  src: url("FZYXJW.ttf");
}

// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('font')
        .test(/\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/)
        .use('url-loader')
        .loader('url-loader')
        .end()
  }
};

// App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app'
}

</script>

<style>
  @import "/assets/font/font.css";

  #app {
    font-family: 'Youxian';
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }

</style>
```

I expected the font to change to "Youxian", but actually nothing happened.